# Does the Burau representation of braids distinguish between distinct elements of the free self-distributive algebras on one generator?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, braid-groups

A well-known but now mostly solved problem in group theory is the question of whether the [Burau representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burau_representation) of the braid groups is faithful. It turns out that this representation is not faithful for $B_{n}$ for $n\geq 5$.

Let $B_{\infty}$ denote the infinite strand braid group. A rack is an algebra $(A,*,*^{-1})$ that satisfies the following identities:

1. $x*(y*z)=(x*y)*(x*z)$
2. $x*^{-1}(x*y)=x*(x*^{-1}y)=y$.

If $(X,*,*^{-1})$ is a rack, then define an action of $B_{\infty}$ on $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ by letting
$$(x_{1},\dots,x_{n},\dots)\sigma_{i}=(x_{1},\dots,x_{i-1},x_{i}*x_{i+1},x_{i},x_{i+2},x_{i+3},\dots).$$
This action of $B_{\infty}$ on $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ is known as the Hurwitz action with respect to the operation $*_{M,\lambda}$.

Suppose now that $M$ is a module over a commutative ring $R$. Let $\lambda\in R$ be invertible.

Define $$x*_{M,\lambda}y=(1-\lambda)x+\lambda y$$ and $$x*_{M,\lambda}^{-1}y=(1-\lambda^{-1})x+\lambda^{-1}y.$$
Then $(M,*_{M,\lambda})$ is a rack. The Burau representation of $B_{\infty}$ 
is the Hurwitz action of $B_{\infty}$ on $M^{\mathbb{N}}$ with respect to $*_{M,\lambda}$ where $M=\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]$ and where $\lambda=t$. The Burau representation on $B_{\infty}$ is not faithful.

Let $\mathrm{sh}:B_{\infty}\rightarrow B_{\infty}$ be the group homomorphism where $\mathrm{sh}(\sigma_{i})=\sigma_{i+1}$. Define an operation $*$ on $B_{\infty}$ defined by $$x*y=x\cdot\mathrm{sh}(y)\cdot\sigma_{1}\cdot\mathrm{sh}(x)^{-1}.$$ Then $(B_{\infty},*)$ satisfies the self-distributivity identity $x*(y*z)=(x*y)*(x*z)$. Furthermore, each $x\in B_{\infty}$ generates a free self-distributive subalgebra of $(B_{\infty},*)$.

Suppose now that $x\in B_{\infty}$. Suppose now that $A_{x}\subseteq B_{\infty}$ is the subalgebra of $(B_{\infty},*)$ generated by $x$. Is the Burau representation injective when restricted to $A_{x}$?